# finding the parent transaction scope's TransactionScopeOption in the child transactionscope

Tags: transactionscope

In a parent transaction scope, i have the TransactionScopeOption of Required.

Later on in a inner transaction scope, i need to check the TransactionScopeOption of the parent transaction scope.

How is this possible..

Example

```
Parent : using (TransactionScope transactionScopeParent = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions))
{
....
method()
}

method()
{
here i need to check the TransactionScopeOption of this transaction scope's parent one and then set this transaction scope to be having the same TransactionScopeOption.

using (TransactionScope transactionScopeChild = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions))
}
```

is this possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is not needed.

If the "parent" `TransactionScope` is `Required`, the nested one will be enrolled it the transactions already.

If it isn't, the nested one will not automatically become "required".

The only exception is if you explicitly set the nested `TransactionScope` to `RequiresNew`, when a new transaction will start.

Comment: Please note that my usage is that an inner transaction will be having its TransactionScope to `suppress` by default, but when there is a parent transactionscope, then i need to change this `suppress` to be inline with the parent transactionscope. kindly confirm

Comment: @saravanan - If you suppress the inner transaction, it will not participate in a transaction. Perhaps you should create two versions of your function - one suppressing transactions and one not.

Comment: I actually have to use this feature for MySQL & SQL transactions. In case of SQL i will allow the child transaction to participate in the parent transaction. In case of MySQL, it will be in a suppressed transaction as MySQL does not support distributed transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your comments to @Oded's answer, you seem to want

- MS SQL connections to participate in `System.Transactions.Transaction`s
- MySQL connections to not participate

To get that behavior, you just need to append

> AutoEnlist=False;

to your [MySQL connection string](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-connection-options.html):

> If `AutoEnlist` is set to `true`, which is the default, a connection
>   opened using `TransactionScope` participates in this scope, it commits
>   when the scope commits and rolls back if `TransactionScope` does not
>   commit. However, this feature is considered security sensitive and
>   therefore cannot be used in a medium trust environment.